# Poisson Distribution (Influenza)

Tags: probability-distributions

The number $X$ of people in a certain town who get the influenza follows a
Poisson distribution. The proportion of people who did not get the flu is
$0.01$. Find the probability mass function of $X$.

Ok so the probability mass function formula is $e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^k}{k!}$. I saw the solution but I do not understand how this was solved?

Comment: This does not make sense.  If the population of the town is $N$, then $0.99 N$ is the number of people who got the flu, i.e. it is an **observation** of $X$.  You could use that as an estimator of the parameter $\lambda$, but you can't say what the true $\lambda$ is.

Comment: Of course, the number who get the flu can't be more than the population of the town, while a Poisson random variable can take arbitrarily large values, so it can't really be Poisson: Poisson is just an approximation.

Answer (score 1):

The only meaningful exercise is

> The number $X$ of people in a certain town who get the influenza
>   follows a Poisson distribution. **The probbility that no one** did get
>   the flu is $0.01$. Find the probability mass function of $X$.

Thus the equation is $P(X=0)=e^{-\lambda}\cdot \frac{\lambda^0}{0!}=0.01$

Thus $\lambda=\ln(100)$